# IIS Web Page Returns "Server Error 500" When I press "Submit" button (POST request)

Tags: django, iis, http-post, web-deployment, server-error

I am using Django framework to create simple web portal for my team. The main purpose of the web portal is to deliver the file to a server using paramiko.SSHClent(). If I run my project on the local server using "python manage.py runserver", then pressing the "Submit" button delivers the file from the user to the server.

The next step was to deploy the website. So, I used Windows Internet Information Service(IIS) Manager 8.5 to deploy my website. The website deployed, but there is one problem. If I press the "Submit" button, I get this error, "Server Error (500)"

Here is the **Detailed Error** image:
[500 Server Error Detail IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUVCE.png)

Here is the **views.py** file:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from .forms import DocumentForm
    from django.contrib import messages
    import paramiko
    import os
    from . import file_mapping


    def uploadForm(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

        document = request.FILES['document']
        client_name = form.cleaned_data.get('client')
        file_type = form.cleaned_data.get('fileType')
        print('Client Name: ' + client_name)
        print('File Type: ' + file_type)

        file_mapping.handle_uploaded_file(document)
        file_mapping.setupfilename(client_name, file_type)
        #file_mapping.connectCqaServer(document)


        messages.success(request, f'Your file has been uploaded.')

    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
        #messages.warning(request, f'Your file is Invalid')

    return render(request, 'forms/forms.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is the **forms.html** file:

```
    {% extends "blog/base.html"%}
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %} 
    {% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
     <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <fieldset class="form-group">
             <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"> Upload Name and File </legend>
             {{ form | crispy }}
         </fieldset>

         <div class="form-group">
             <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Upload</button>
         </div>
     </form>
    </div>
    {%endblock content %}
```

Here is the **Handler Mapping** settings on the IIS Manager:
[HANDLER MAPPING IMAGE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8AYo.png)

Here is the **IIS Log**:

```
    2020-05-06 18:23:52 10.137.11.223 POST /forms/ - 80 - 10.25.75.1 
    Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+ 
    (KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/81.0.4044.129+Safari/537.36 
    http://spscvt.com/forms/ 500 0 0 164
```

**I DO NOT HAVE WEBDAV INSTALLED**

Can someone please help out with this issue? From my research online, I found out that IIS doesn't allow POST method, but I don't know to remove POST restriction.

Thanks

Comment: That log is ... well, not informative at all. IIS does allow POST method, it's not that. Setup some proper logging. It's guessing without logs. In the meantime, if you are saving the file, check that IIS user has permission to the directory where you the file is supposed to be saved and comment out parts of code until you find where it's failing.

Comment: IIS just works as a proxy and the application user is application pool identity not your current loggon user. The error message show that error was thrown from python cgi. So have you tried to set application pool identity to an admin account or local system. It will help us narrow down whether thats a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft IIS creates something called [AppPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/). By default you will have a user `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool`. That user needs to have permissions to your database and other necessary files to read *and* write.

If they do not, it will return the 500 error. You can look at this clip here to see how to fix the error [Django on IIS with 500 error](https://youtu.be/APCQ15YqqQ0?t=1137).

In order to give permissions you can follow these steps

1. Right-click your Django project folder
2. Properties --> Security
3. Edit --> Add: `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` or whatever app pool you're using
4. Restart your server and test again

### Edit

I didn't see that you attached an image. I think you need to allow `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` access to Python also. Follow the steps above with reference to the directory pointing to your Python installation (this includes your `venv`)